# ListView OwnerDraw with AllowColumnReorder don't work correct

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I'm drawing custom ListView, with OwnerDraw property set to 'true'. Also listview has AllowColumnReorder 'true' property.

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
}
```

This is working fine:

[image]

But if I move the first column there is a drawing problem - data from first two columns is painted in frist column, and the data from the column which was moved is not painted at all:

[image]

This happens because e.Bounds has equals values for two differents columns. What can I do to get correct e.Bounds value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Hans Passant for info. I fixed this bug using next code:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = e.Bounds;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex != 0)
        {
            bounds = GetFirstColumnCorrectRectangle(e.Item);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, bounds);
    }

    private Rectangle GetFirstColumnCorrectRectangle(ListViewItem item)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            if (listView1.Columns[i].DisplayIndex == listView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex - 1)
                break;
        return new Rectangle(item.SubItems[i].Bounds.Right, item.SubItems[i].Bounds.Y, listView1.Columns[0].Width, item.SubItems[i].Bounds.Height);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a bug in ListView class.  Its private [GetItemRectOrEmpty() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,ab499eb20bbfa927) is borken.  Written as a bug workaround, internal bug number VSWhidbey #163674.  Having a bug fix cause another bug is a pretty traditional programming mishap, the big boys make them too :)  When it asks Windows for the item rectangle, passed to you through the e.Bounds property, it flubs and asks for ItemBoundsPortion.Entire.  Which is the complete ListViewItem rectangle, including the subitems.

Luckily the workaround is simple, you can use ItemBoundsPortion.ItemOnly yourself:

```
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e) {
    var bounds = e.Bounds;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
        bounds = listView1.GetItemRect(e.ItemIndex, ItemBoundsPortion.ItemOnly);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, bounds);
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. GetItemRect method returns full item rectangle. But DisplayIndex property for column_0 didn't become 0 when I moved this column. How can I get rectangle for current subitem?

Comment: I tested this pretty thoroughly, worked fine.  You are doing something else that I don't know about.  Otherwise the liability of expecting someone to fix a bug from a screenshot.